# Change iTerm2 Profile

Tags: macos, iterm

**How can I change the profile of my current iTerm2 session?**

If I click Profiles and select one, it opens a new session instead of changing the current one.

Comment: I'm looking for functionality offered out of the box by Gnome Terminal.

Comment: That explanation should be in the question not in comments. Also what does Gnome Terminal offer out of the box - most people here won't have used it.

Comment: There is also possibility for Automatic Profile Switching (Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Automatic Profile Switching). Shell integration must be installed and: "Any session will switch to this profile automatically when your hostname, username and current path match a rule below. A rule may specify username, hostname, path, or job"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to "Edit" the session.

The easiest way to do this is to right click on anywhere on the open iTerm2 window, select *Edit Session...*  A *Preferences* pane will appear and under the *General* tab, look for the *Profile Name* selection box.   Double click on your desired profile.

Comment: maybe it's a bug, but double-clicking on a '22 MacBook pro (without touchbar) doesn't change the profile. I'm used to being able to press a color preset on the touchbar. But I just assigned a shortcut to the profile so its all good.

Comment: You can get to the _Edit Session..._ window by pressing cmd+i

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using iterm2 profile keys (these are handy shortcuts which you can add yourself)

1. In iTerm's preferences, select the `keys` tab.
2. There's a table called `key mappings`, click on the `+` at the bottom of the table
3. Choose a keyboard shortcut From the dropdown menu, search and choose for change profile option and assign a shortcut.
4. Remember these are shortcut keys when you present in the respective profile, so if you switch profile and toggle back, you need to add a shortcut in the other profile

It works across all panes and windows and its setting is persistent across sessions.

This works on iTerm2 (version, 3.0.8 to Build 3.4.6)
[Reference](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-keys.html)

Comment: is there a way to 'script' this key mapping. e.g. set up 4 keybindings from running a CLI script. would be nice when setting up a new cmputer instead of using the GUI

Answer (score 1):

To add other profiles and change the default you need to go to the Profiles menu and choose Open Profile... key for that is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

This gives a panel where you can edit all the existing profiles and run them .

Documentation is at https://iterm2.com/documentation-menu-items.html